# Помогите портировать управление (Мобилка + ввод мыши) Unity!

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Нужно переделать управление под мышку. Скрипт сначала был написан для мобильного, но нужно делать тест и на компьютере.
Нужно сделать через #if unity_editor #endif

```
public Vector2 startPos;
    public Vector3 direction;

if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
            Vector3 touchPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToViewportPoint(touch.position);
            
            switch (touch.phase)
            {
                case TouchPhase.Began:
                    parabora.GetComponent<LineRenderer>().enabled = true;
                    startPos = touch.position;
                    break;
               
                case TouchPhase.Moved:
                    
                    direction.x = touch.position.x - startPos.x;
                    
                        parabolaPoint.position += direction * pointMoovingSpeed;
                    

                    Shoot();
                    break;

                    
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Будет как-то так. Не очень понял, зачем нужна `touchPosition`, вы к ней нигде не обращаетесь.

Более того, методы `Input.GetMouseButton(0)` и `Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)` прекрасно работают и на мобилках, как тачи, так что можно оставить только их.

Хотя конечно может у `TouchPhase.Moved` какая-то хитрая проверка на то, что палец действительно двинулся, не помню, тогда придется реализовываться какой-то фильтр и для мышки

```
#if !UNITY_EDITOR
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
        Vector3 touchPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToViewportPoint(touch.position);

        switch (touch.phase)
        {
            case TouchPhase.Began:
                parabora.GetComponent<LineRenderer>().enabled = true;
                startPos = touch.position;
                break;

            case TouchPhase.Moved:

                direction.x = touch.position.x - startPos.x;

                parabolaPoint.position += direction * pointMoovingSpeed;


                Shoot();
                break;
        }
    }
#else
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        parabora.GetComponent<LineRenderer>().enabled = true;
        startPos = Input.mousePosition;
    }
    else if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        Vector3 touchPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToViewportPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        direction.x = Input.mousePosition.x - startPos.x;
        parabolaPoint.position += direction * pointMoovingSpeed;
        Shoot();
    }
#endif
```

Comment: Дублирование кода. Грех.

Comment: Грех это не кешировать GetComponent и Camera.main, но тут о другом вопрос =)

Comment: А это вообще уголовно наказуемо должно быть =D

Comment: Input.touches[0] аллоцирует. Грех. (не могу к вашему ответу коммент добавить пока)

Comment: Пошла проповедь XD

Comment: Мне как раз надо moved переделать). С тем я почти разобрался, а с мувом такое

Comment: @diver6ent в моем примере Moved находится под `Input.GetMouseButton(0)`

Comment: да да, мувд работает) Но не работает отжатие левой кнопки). Получается я зажимаю, могу целиться, а когда отжимаю не стреляет. в методе выстрел такое условие: if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0) && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Ended)

Comment: @diver6ent зачем вам && это же проверки для разных типов управления. Т.е. нужна проверка на `Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)` если это `#if UNITY_EDITOR`, а `Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Ended` для остального

Comment: сделал, спасибо всем! цьом!

Answer (score 1):

Кстати, `Input.touches` работает в редакторе...

```
private void Update () {
    UpdateInputs();
}

private void UpdateInputs () {
    #if UNITY_EDITOR
    UpdateMouse();
    #else
    UpdateTouch();
    #endif
}

private void UpdateMouse () {
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        InputBegan(Input.mousePosition);
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        InputMove(Input.mousePosition);
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        InputEnd(Input.mousePosition);
}

private void UpdateTouch () {
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches)
            switch (touch.phase) {
                case TouchPhase.Began: InputBegan(touch.position); break;
                case TouchPhase.Moved: InputMove(touch.position); break;
                case TouchPhase.Ended: InputEnd(touch.position); break;
        }
}

private void InputBegan (Vector2 position) {
    /* ...code... */
}

private void InputMove (Vector2 position) {
    /* ...code... */
}

private void InputEnd (Vector2 position) {
    /* ...code... */
}
```